# Core-plot bar chart pan event

Tags: ios, charts, swift, core-plot

I'm going to create an iPad application to show and modify bar charts (where every bar is composed by a stack of little rectangles), so I'm evaluating chart frameworks Swift-compatible.

I started to evaluate CorePlot framework and it is a good candidate, supposing to import it in Xcode following [this](http://blog.alwold.com/2014/08/07/using-coreplot-with-swift-in-ios/) guide.

Although I already took a look to the available tutorials, I couldn't find anything for the following scenario:

1. draw a chart showing 24 bars representing data coming from a JSON string, obtained from a service call
2. vertically pan the top of a bar, so that such bar grows or decreases accordingly
3. send to the service the new MODIFIED data associated to the chart

Can anyone notify here a link to tutorials/guides for such a case, please?

Thanks

Comment: are you able to get core plot to work with swift?  I've had some difficulty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Core Plot doesn't care where the data comes from. It's up to the datasource to translate it to numeric values before passing them to the plot. JSON parsing is outside the scope of a plotting library like Core Plot.
2. I'm not sure what you're asking in #2. It's easy to update the plot with new data and resize the visible parts of the plot area to display it, but that's the responsibility of the controller object and the datasource.
3. Core Plot is for display only. Any interaction with external services is the responsibility of the controller object.

Comment: I was trying to give the target global vision of the program, then ok for #1 and #3.
For #2, i need to give the user the ability to resize the vertical bar via pan gesture, starting from the top of the bar. This action should automatically modify the data bound to that bar. Is it possible to do that?

Is there any tutorial showing this?

Comment: You can update a single data point to follow the user's finger. You could use a plot area delegate to track the touch interaction and adjust the plot data in response.